# Warning when trying to change boot mode to AHCI

Tags: uefi, nvme, ahci, intel-rst

When I try to change boot mode in my laptop to AHCI, it gives me such warning:
[image]

I need this change to dual-boot Linux with Windows.
I have one non-RAID NVMe SSD.

Thanks for help

Comment: Dual booting and the controller mode are two separate things.  Why are you changing the mode?

Comment: Because Linux doesn't support RST controller mode

Comment: Thats at the BIOS level, Linux doesnt care.  It only matters if you want to run the Intel RST software, which isnt necessary.